# Apache Starting Error and all log files are empty

Tags: apache, localhost, ubuntu-12.04

When i try to start my apache2 in ubuntu, it displays following error.

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                     
  AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:8
  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
  (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:8080
  no listening sockets available, shutting down
  AH00015: Unable to open logs
  Action 'start' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.
  * 
  * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

And My log files in `var/log/apache2/` files `error.log`,`acces.log` files not updated after i emptied it.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some other service is already using port 8080. Run

```
# netstat -lnpt
```

to see what it is.